# Use apache httpclient 4.3.2 and httpclient 4.1.2 at the same time

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm stuck in a project where I have two dependencies that seem to be contradicting themselves.

One lib is apache's httpClient 4.1.* and the other is apache's HttpClient 4.3.*.

Is there a way to have HttpClient 4.3.* and keep it backwards compatible with 4.1.*?
According to the javadoc, the interface is deprecated, not removed.

When I try to use just the 4.3.2, I get:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext

I'm running on Tomcat 7.0.50 and I'm running on eclipse

Comment: It is depracated not removed for backwards compatibility, so i guess it is quite straight forward answer

Comment: Indeed, if the interface/method you require is only deprecated, why do you need to include the older JAR?

Comment: @Antoniossss Nope... I still get: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext

Comment: Are you using an Apache Tomcat server? If so, which version?

Comment: If you are placing your JAR's in WEB-INF/libs folder, then try moving them into the Tomcat/libs folder. I've had similar issues recently and that normally fixed it for me.

Comment: @munyul Bah! The issue was way different from anything that seemed to be but your solution gave me the spark I required to get the answer. Thank you! I'll fix the question and write an answer just in case someone else encounters something similar

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this happened because of the IDE I am using (eclipse) even though I once tell that I want to use all dependencies on the server I have it associated with (in this case, tomcat 7.0), It didn't update when I had added this HttpClient 4.3.2.
Furthermore, the program was giving problems in one of the sub-systems that was requiring 4.1.* in a class that is classified as deprecated in 4.3.2.

It was just a series of coincidences (and misreading the manual or gap in the manual) that lead to my misinterpretation of what was really happening.

On **eclipse**, to add libraries from the project to make them available from the server, use this tool:

`project -> properties -> deployment assembly`